# scipy.sparse lil_matrix: __iadd__ operator

Tags: python, scipy

I am facing a very strange behaviour in the computation of the sum bewteen two lil_matrix. Please find below the code

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
a = lil_matrix([100])
print(a.todense())
a += lil_matrix([-100])
print(a.todense())
```

I would expect a result equals to 0 as it happens with

```
print((lil_matrix([100])+lil_matrix([-100])).todense())
```

Can someone help understanding the issue?

please find below the versions
python 3.8.5
scipy 1.5.2

Thanks

Comment: I do get `[[0]]` in python 3.8.6 and scipy 1.5.4 (closest versions I had around). What are you getting?

Comment: @MikaelÖhman from the first lines I get [[100]]

Comment: I can reproduce with scipy 1.4.1. This just seems to be a straight up bug in scipy. Seems to only trigger in this particular case where you subtract exact values and obtain all new zeros on all positions. Perhaps a bug in the code that resets the sparse structure. The only option is to update your scipy. 1.5.4 seems to work correctly.

Comment: `lil` format was added primarily as input tool.  `csr` is the primary calculation format.  So I'm not surprised that there might be bugs in this newish  operation.  Sparse matrices do not subclass `ndarray`, so a lot of math is incomplete, or slower. (or in some cases does not make sense)